# Получить список установленных программ календаря

Tags: android, calendar

Как получить список установленных программ календаря и связанных с ними аккаунтов. например у меня установлены гугл календарь,s-planner, outlook

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor cursor;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{"_id", "displayName"}, null, null, null);
        } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 14) {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
                    new String[]{"_id", "displayName"}, null, null, null);
        } else {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
                    new String[]{"_id", "calendar_displayName"}, null, null, null);
        }
        // Get calendars name
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String[] calendarNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            // Get calendars id
            int calendarIds[] = new int[cursor.getCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                calendarIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
                calendarNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
                Log.i("Calendar Name : " + calendarNames[i]);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("No calendar found in the device");
        }
```

Для этого вам нужно использовать [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver). Предварительно вы должна получить [Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) `READ_CALENDAR & WRITE_CALENDAR`.

Еще вам стоит почитать документацию про [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider?hl=ru). Там так же есть примеры кода и в целом описание того как это работает.